# PyQt Calculator- Not getting Result

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

In the following Program, the calculator gui is closing itself when i press "=" for getting the result. I think there is some problem with the eval function. if i remove the eval then i didn't encounter any problem with the program. Need help in figuring this out. Is there any other approach i can try besides this? Thanks in advance.

```
    class Calci(QWidget):

        def __init__(self, Parent=None):



            super(Calci,self).__init__()

            self.initgui()



        def initgui(self):

            self.list1= 

   ["%","rt","pow","1/x","CE","C","BCK","/","7","8","9","*","4","5","6","- 
   ","1","2","3","+","+-","0",".","="]

            self.list2=[(i,j) for i in range(2,8) for j in range(0,4)]

            self.button={}

            self.data1=""

            self.data2=0

            self.lineedit=QLineEdit()

            self.lineedit.setFocus()

            grid=QGridLayout() 

            self.setLayout(grid)

            self.font=QFont("Bookman Old Style",15,25)

            self.lineedit.setFont(self.font)

            for x,y in zip(self.list1,self.list2):



                self.button[y]=QPushButton(x)

                grid.addWidget(self.lineedit,0,0,2,4)


    self.lineedit.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,QSizePolicy.Expanding)

                self.lineedit.setMinimumHeight(70)

                grid.addWidget(self.button[y],*y)





   self.button[y].setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,QSizePolicy.Expanding)

                self.button[y].setMinimumHeight(70)

                self.lineedit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

                self.button[y].clicked.connect(lambda state,x=x: self.click(x))





        def click(self,n):





                if (n=="="):



                   data1=self.lineedit.text()



                   self.lineedit.clear()

                   self.lineedit.insert(eval(data1))



                else:

                   self.lineedit.insert(n)













    app=QApplication(sys.argv)

    calci=Calci()

    calci.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely failing because of a `TypeError` when you try to set the line edit text to an integer value.  I also don't think `self.lineedit.insert()` is the method that you want to use.  This will add the calculation after the line after the text already entered.

try:

```
self.lineedit.setText(str(eval(data1)))
```

This will clear the line edit and set the text to the calculated value.

**But:**

Please don't use `eval` like this.  This is a very dangerous practice as any python code entered in the text edit will be run.

Comment: I am clearing the lineedit (self.lineedit.clear())before inserting the result.Is this going to pose any problem? Also can u shed some light on how should i use eval in this code?

Comment: I missed the `clear()` call before that line somehow.  In that case you should be fine.  If you do use `setText()` instead you can do away with the `clear()` call.  In this scenario I wouldn't use `eval` at all.  I would parse the text string to get the integers and operators then convert the integer types and perform the correct operation.  If you absolutely must use `eval`, I would at least check the string entered to make sure it isn't malicious.

Comment: I got your point. I still have one query. What do you mean by this line "any python code in the text edit will be run". Can u pls elaborate the warning ?

Comment: `eval` works by running a string as python code.  You can use this to evaluate mathematical expressions, as you are, but it will execute any code it receives as input, not just mathematical operations.  [This explains more.](https://www.kevinlondon.com/2015/07/26/dangerous-python-functions.html#code-injection---exec-eval)